# Is there an earlier hook than login_head or login_enqueue_scripts?

Tags: plugins, css, hooks, javascript, wp-login-form

## What I have:

A basic plugin that enqueues a style-sheet and JavaScript file to modify the log-in forms. The logo, colour scheming and other styles are affected.

## My problem:

As the `/wp-login.php` page loads, the default layout is presented for 1 to 2 seconds before my plugin kicks in and only then are the plugin's modifications are applied. Both the CSS and JavaScript are lagging therefore it's the plugin as a whole.

## My question:

How can I enqueue my styles/scripts so that the plugin doesn't take 1-2 seconds apply (or how can I simply force my plugin in general to apply instantaneously)?

Answer (score 1):

The hooks are fine for change the login style. I think is better idea to identifier, why is the load so much slow. I have a lot of change for different installs and no problems with this hooks. But I see also often a lot of loads of unused source. I change the login style with this class: https://github.com/bueltge/wordpress-basis-theme/tree/namespace/inc/admin
Maybe the source helps you.